# ¿Cómo comprobar que un map contiene una clave?

Tags: java

He creado un map, cuya clave es la clase Asignatura y el valor un `ArrayList` de la clase Alumno.

`Map<Asignatura, List<Alumno>> mapa = new HashMap<>();`

Tengo una variable **a** de la clase Asignatura.

Quiero comprobar si el map contiene esa clave, pero no consigo que entre en el if.

```
if(mapa.containsKey(a))
{
    System.out.println("Contiene la clave");
}
```

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Pon el código donde insertas la clave y hasta donde la buscas con ese `if`. Lo más seguro es que estés instaciando otro objeto con la misma información y creas que por eso tiene que darte `true` esa evaluación, pero sólo te dará `true` si es el mismo objeto, no otro con el mismo contenido.

Comment: Si el map contiene la clave , actualiza valor? Mismo valor? Explícate mejor porfavor!

Comment: Se necesita un [mcve], en particular, por favor incluye el contenido de la clase `Asignatura`. Pero lo más probable es que el problema es lo que menciona @Pablo en su [respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/39329/18951).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usar `Map#containsKey(llave)` es la forma correcta de verificar si la llave existe en el mapa. Si no te devuelve el resultado esperado (`true`) entonces la causa es que la llave no esté siendo identificada como única. Para determinar esta unicidad, tenemos que ver la implementación de `Map` usada:

1. Las implementaciones `HashMap`, `LinkedHashMap` y `ConcurrentHashMap` usan los métodos `hashCode` y `equals` para identificar la unicidad de la llave. Debes asegurarte que estos métodos estén implementados apropiadamente en la clase que usas como llave.
2. Las implementaciones `TreeMap` y `ConcurrentSkipMap` usan el orden natural de las llaves para identificarlas. Para ello, la clase de la llave debe implementar la interfaz `Comparable` o se debe proveer un `Comparator<K>` (donde `K` es el tipo de la llave) que permita identificar si una llave es mayor, menor o igual a otra.

Como indicas que usas un `HashMap`, entonces conviene revisar la implementación de los métodos `hashCode` y `equals` en tu clase `Asignatura` y ver que devuelvan los valores apropiados para identificar la igualdad del objeto que estás enviando. Si provees la definición de esta clase, se puede refinar la respuesta.

Comment: Me parece increíble que con la reputación que tienes aún respondas preguntas que debían haber sido cerradas por no estar claro lo que pregunta.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n para mí es claro lo que se pregunta. Si para ti no lo es, puedes votar a cierre.

Comment: Lo hice hace un buen rato, sobretodo cuando vi tantas respuestas a un problema que puede tener varias causas. Unas directamente con mala práctica y otras a ver si suena la flauta. Por eso también voté a todas en negativo. Estas preguntas y estas repuestas son las que van a mediocrizar esta comunidad.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema puede estar en que no hayas sobreescrito los métodos hashCode y equals en Asignatura, que si no recuerdo mal, son los que usan los Hash. Si no lo has hecho, creo que sólo entrará cuando "a" sea la misma referencia que has insertado en el Hash

Comment: Si no está claro cuál es el problema que tiene una persona es mejor poner un comentario a una respuesta incompleta o que acierte por puro azar. Cuando el OP nos de la información que hace falta es cuando habrá que solucionarle el problema identificado. Te lo digo a ti igual que se lo digo al resto de respuestas en esta pregunta. Un respuesta incompleta o con un invento es peor que no tenerla pues puede confundir a cualquiera. Además no hace falta sobrescribir los métodos que dices para `HashMap`, podría dar peores resultados el método por defecto, pero funcionará.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n estás equivocado. Para un `HashMap`, los métodos `hashCode` y `equals` son la clave para determinar si la llave es única en el mapa.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza te aseguro que no hace falta para que funcione. Mira bien el tema y te darás cuenta de ello. Evidentemente si tienes bien implementados esos dos métodos todo será mejor, pero en general, no hace falta para que te funcione aceptablemente. Yo estoy harto de hacer `HashMap`s en listas con decenas de miles de elementos y nunca he tenido ni un fallo, ni una excepción de rotura del contrato. No es como en `TreeMap` que si no implementa `Comparable` ni va a compilar. El OP no tiene este problema, estoy convencido de ello. Lo más probable es lo que puse en el comentario de la pregunta

Comment: @Awes0meM4n he visto esta misma situación en varias preguntas de SOen, es muy probable que el patrón se repita aquí.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza si es así no sé porque no has votado para cerrar esta pregunta por duplicada. Me parece increíble que con la reputación que tienes aún respondas preguntas que debían haber sido cerradas por no estar claro lo que pregunta.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n no conozco una respuesta en SOes sobre esto. Solo de SOen (nótese la N en el comentario que puse). Si la conociera, créeme que la hubiese cerrado.

Comment: He encontrado este articulo, que puede que arroje un poco de luz:

Comment: Disculpad, es el primer comentario que pongo y se me ha escapado. El artículo: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/39316/c%c3%b3mo-comprobar-que-un-map-contiene-una-clave

Comment: Y además me la ha jugado el portapapeles. Mil disculpas: http://www.arquitecturajava.com/entiendo-los-metodos-de-java-equals-y-hashcode/

Answer (score -1):

Para que encuentre valores en la tabla, antes tienes que meter las claves con los valores.

```
mapa.put(a, lista);
if (mapa.contains(a))
    System.out.println("Contiene la clave");
```

Comment: No veo la definición de `Map#contains` en la definición de [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). Lo que hay es `containsKey`. El código provisto no compila.

Answer (score -2):

```
Map<Asignatura, List<Alumno>> mapa = new HashMap<>();
//aquí deberías tener un bucle que se le pasa "p" al map.get()
if(mapa.contains(a)){
       map.get(p).addAll(p.getAlumno()); //es una lsita , es un tipo mutable por     tanto no es necesario que hagas el put
}else{
 //en caso de que no esté , se asocia clave-valor nuevas.
 List<Alumno>alum= new ArrayList<Alumno>();
        alum.addAll(p.getAlumnos());
        map.put(p, alum);
}
```

Lo he hecho más o menos como es típico pero obviamente no te expresas muy bien con lo que quieres , te dejo aquí algo , por si te sirve de ayuda.

Comment: No veo la definición de `Map#contains` en la definición de [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). Lo que hay es `containsKey`. El código provisto no compila.